# Schedule daily Docker container restart / reset

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Linux based Docker container running an application which seems to have a memory leak. After around a week requests to the application start to fail and the container requires a restart to reset its state and get things working again.

The error reported by the application is:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there a generic method that can be used to trigger a restart, resetting it's state, regardless of which service is being used to host it? If there's not a good generic solution, I'm about to give DigitalOcean a whirl so maybe there's a DigitalOcean specific solution that may work instead?

Comment: You can add a cronjob to restart it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the cronjob option as sounds promising.

Comment: As a reference, I use `30 1 * * * docker restart container_name` to restart a container every day at 01:30 at night. You can get the container_name by running `docker ps`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need more fine-grained scheduling, I took @Marvin's answer here and modified it for an in-line sh script. This example schedules a daily reset of the containers at within 60 seconds of 8pm UTC:

```
version: "3"
services:

  myservice:
    container_name: myservice
      
  restarter:
    image: docker:cli
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
      - |
        while true; do
          if [ "$$(date +'%H:%M')" = '20:00' ]; then
            docker restart myservice
          fi
          sleep 60
        done
```

Comment: Does this work on UTC irrespective of server time zone ?

Comment: @KiKMak It should. If you're not sure, you can just try adjusting the script and echo out the time, and then review the logs.

Comment: ok tried it out, it's working in UTC

Comment: I got "Invalid interpolation format" and needed to escape the `$` by doubling it.

Answer (score 1):

have you ever seen this answer below :
[Restart container from docker compose](https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/782b500a81ce46b889903b1f80353f21)

you should to try, i've tried that for my project & work properly.

or you can try this on your docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  voice_to_text:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    image: marvinhris/vtt_fw
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: ${RESTART}
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: ${MEMORY}
    memswap_limit: ${SWAP_LIMIT}
    expose:
      - ${EXPOSE_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${EXPOSE_PORT}
    command: >
      bash -c "gunicorn --workers=${WORKER_TOTAL} --threads=${THREADS} --bind=${HOST}:${EXPOSE_PORT} --worker-class=${WORKER} --timeout=${TIMEOUT} wsgi:server"
  restarter:
    image: docker:cli
    volumes: ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"]
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do sleep 86400; docker restart ${CONTAINER_NAME}; done"]
    restart: ${RESTART}
```

on my code above, its running a stack named "voice_to_text" with two service, one as a main service, second is restarter.

if you have a docker compose file, you only need add code for restarter services, and i set it up for 86400 seconds or 24 Hours to restart the main service

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a restart policy (with flag `on-failure`) as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

Comment: I'm guessing it might not get triggered in this case as the container seems to be working, the app hosted within is failing instead.

Answer (score -3):

Check out the [Watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) project. This is an incredible tool that restarts Docker containers on schedule and also updates containers automatically.

Comment: Looks interesting but I'm hoping to not need a 2nd container to manage the 1st container if possible. It looks like Watchtower will need hosting independently.

Comment: Watchtower is not an appropriate answer here; it will _only_ restart a container when a new version of the image is published. The question calls for a container to be restarted either on a regular schedule, or perhaps when a specific error is detected in the container's log.